# Keep dynamiclly added controls in PlaceHolder after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, placeholder

In my asp.net page I put PlaceHolder control and after clicking a button user can place some stuff to it (example: another controls). But after postback PlaceHolder is empty again. Is it possible to maintain all programmaticlly added controls in PlaceHolder and clear it only when user wont to do it?

```
<div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" ></asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>

<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="addcontent" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="postback" />
</div>
```

codebehind

```
       protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image newImage = new Image();
        newImage.ImageUrl = "~/bear.jpg";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(newImage);            
    }
```

I would like avoid overriding SaveViewState and LoadViewState.

Comment: What about using a `<asp:UpdatePanel />` do you know how to do it?

Comment: thank you for clue, I know basics about it but I do research about UpdatePanel features

Comment: Check out my answer, it's an exemple of how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Using `<asp:UpdatePanel />`:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scrpManager" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="myUpdtPanel">   
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" >

                    </asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="addcontent" onclick="Button1_Click" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="postback" />
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>         
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I use it, and It is the same. First I click addcontent button and image appears. Next, After clicking postback button, image disappears.

Comment: Why exactly do you need the postback for?

Comment: One function of the page is to allow user to dynamically add some picture and text, but also page has a lot of other controls for other functionality and they needs a postback.

Comment: If you add everything inside the `<asp:UpdataPanel />` they won't need to do postback. Is it possible for you to add every control inside it?

Comment: I thing it will be very hard to push all controls to UpdatePanel. I do not get why controls do not need postback if they in UpdatePanel. In example first button adds some content, second does some other stuff and needs to process some data on the server. So I think postback is necessary.

Comment: When you add your control inside a `<asp:UpdatePanel />` it basically creates ajax functions for you and handles everything you would need to do manualy if you wanted to do that via javascript (a way to change pages content with no postbacks) without postbacks.

Comment: It is useful but I think not for my problem. Maybe overriding ViewState methods will be only solution. Thanks for all your comments.

Comment: No problem. However, there're others ways to achieve that, you can push into the **[User Session Sate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)** all added controls Id's and on the page_load event **[identify if it's either a PostBack or not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx)** then you can render all controls again. You can also save these controls Id's into the **[Cookeis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495(v=vs.71).aspx)** rather than using Session if you'd like to.